# LLC ZVS deadtime calculation

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, zvs, llc-converter

According to the TI LLC [document](https://www.ti.com/seclit/ml/slup263/slup263.pdf), I can use eq 32 to calculate the dead time to achieve the ZVS in the half-bridge LLC Converter.

[image]

below is my spec of half bridge of LLC converter.

[image]

[image]

the deadtime I calculated value is around 452ns.
but when I use this value and run the simulation, I think the dead time is too much.
the Vds2 is already zero.
I am confused about why eq 32 can't match the simulation.

[image]

Simulation result:

[image]
[image]

Comment: What load current phase are you measuring at?

Comment: @TimWilliams
Around 145A

Comment: But amperage is not a phase angle... What matters is drain current at the instant of commutation. Note the relation is equal *or greater* so it's not clear what your confusion is about; the value seems perfectly adequate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run the calculation in my seminar on the [LLC converter](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Introduction%20to%20the%20LLC%20Converter.pdf) and the results are shown below for a 245-kHz switching frequency and two fixed 120-pF parasitic capacitors:

[image]

So, approximately, the zero-voltage switching or ZVS condition would be met in 34 ns or so when the half-bridge transitions. Let's check with the ready-made template you can download [here](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf):

[image]

The transition is realized in 31 ns which is well in par with the calculation. A deadtime of 40-50 ns would then do the job nicely.

In your simulation, check that you are well in steady-state condition and have a look at the peak magnetizing current which should be routed in these capacitors for proper operation.

Comment: Hi
I have checked the waveform is stable. 
I update the waveform here.
what do you mean by the peak magnetizing current which should be routed in these capacitors for proper operation.

Comment: In my simulation, the ZVS only needs 300ns. but the calculated value is 452ns
I think the range is too big.

Comment: I try to use your ready-made template, and using my spec, the result is the same as mine.

Comment: Try to measure the peak magnetizing current and compare it with the expression given for \$I_m\$. The amount of current in these caps determines their discharge/charge times. Then check which in the expressions that I used in the illustration deviates significantly from what is expected.

Comment: Ok, I knew it. 
it seems misunderstand something in there.